# Access remote server file from Shiny web app

Tags: excel, server, shiny

My Shiny app is running perfeclty locally but I have troubles when I deploy it on my R Shiny server (Ubuntu). My app has to read an Excel file located on a remote Windows server. Locally, no problem, but on server I get this error :

> Warning: Error in read.xlsx.default: File does not exist.
>     118: stop
>     117: read.xlsx.default

I guess it is a rights issue. How could I mount my Windows server to access it when I launch my Shiny app to access the Excel file ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Install rstudio server https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download-server/ and try to access your app via port 8787 then check permissions

Comment: How do you reference the path of the file in the shiny server? Is the file at the same location as in your local machine?
If your windows server provides the files via samba, check e.g. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently

Comment: I've had success mounting Windows drives on my linux machine using `cifs-utils` and accessing the data within a Shiny app. I recommend looking into it: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1050460/how-to-mount-smb-share-on-ubuntu-18-04